# Android Mobile Push via MarketingCloudSDK not received

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I'm working on integrating MarketingCloudSDK on Android.
It looks like everything is connecting properly and I see the devices registered. When sending push notifications, it said the message was delivered, but I never got the notification on the device.

Looking at the troubleshooting guides here:
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Says that the payload is:

```
{ "data": { "title": "Test Push", "alert": "It Worked!" }}
```

I looked at Firebase documentation and it says that for the notification, the payload should be using "notification" as the key such as

```
{ "notification": { "title": "Test Push", "alert": "It Worked!" }}
```

When I changed from "data" to "notification" from the troubleshooting step, I was able to get the notification.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You have not followed the documentation on the page you linked.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not posting the whole thing because when changing from "data" to "notification", I'm getting the notification

Comment: The directions on the page you linked work as documented.  Is your application configured with more than 1 push provider?  (Marketing Cloud and Firebase, or ... ???). We have more than 2 billion installations working without incident.  If the directions on the page you linked do not work then you have configured something incorrectly.  I suspect when you change `data` to `notification` then the Firebase service is handling the message and not the MC SDK.

Comment: Correct, I have two providers, Marketing Cloud and Firebase. Isn't Marketing Cloud piggyback on top of Firebase?

Comment: Yes and no.  Please ensure you've followed the documentation with regards to Multiple Push Providers: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html

Comment: got it, yes, that was the culprit. needed to add the handler within the FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived. Thank you!

Comment: @BillMote another thing is I don't see the "opened" status updated after clicking the notification. do you have to do any additional step to update the opened status?

Comment: Assuming you have enabled Analytics when you're initializing the SDK, are you overriding notification handling within your application?  If so, you need to use the SDK's convenience method to wrap the PendingIntent for analytics.  You should only do this if you're completely handling the display of the notification otherwise you'll double-report opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I implemented the notification handler, FirebaseMessagingService. So I had to implement the MarketingCloud handler within onMessageReceived

```
if(PushMessageManager.isMarketingCloudPush(remoteMessage)) {
        MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk( sdk -> {
            sdk.getPushMessageManager().handleMessage(remoteMessage);
        });
    }
```

as described here: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html

Thanks Bill Mote for pointing this out!